# Run the PsExec without knowing the full path in C# Windows application Form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cmd

I need help with my application, I created an application that when they hit the update button will execute some PsExec file to remotetly run some functions. the problem comes that works good in my machine locally but my application will be shared to a lot of users. and I don't want to install to all users the PsExec file to their computers, I just want my program to be installed in their computers and just run the program without any issues.

My code works all the application I just need to add that piece of code that will make the program call the PsExec without knowing the whole Path, right now I installed the PsExec file to my Debug folder, which is the folder that is in my project.

So instead of using the whole PsExec path that is on my directory i will like to use the one of my project

I don't want to use this

```
string leMars21StArguments = @"/C C:\PowerShellRemotly\PsExec.exe " + 
    @"-i \\VML-2012-QBOOK2 -u mydomain\" + userInfo.Username + " -p " + 
    userInfo.Password + " -d C:\\batch\\myfile.bat";
```

I would like something like this where the debug folder of the project, but it doesn't work. is there another to do this?

```
string leMars21StArguments = @"/C Debug\PsExec.exe " + 
    @"-i \\VML-2012-QBOOK2 -u mydomain\" + userInfo.Username + " -p " + 
    userInfo.Password + " -d C:\\batch\\myfile.bat";
```

Here's the full code:

```
Process p = new Process();                    

//assigned from the form txtboxes to the UserInformation class 
userInfo.Username = txt_Username.Text;
userInfo.Password = txt_Password.Text;

//string variabes for the cmd arguments
string leMars21StArguments = @"/C C:\PowerShellRemotly\PsExec.exe -i " + 
    @"\\VML-2012-QBOOK2 -u mydomain\" + userInfo.Username + " -p " + 
    userInfo.Password + " -d C:\\batch\\myfile.bat";

if (userInfo.Username == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username cannot be null, please try again");
}

if (userInfo.Password == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Password cannot be null, please try again");
}

if (cmb_DatabaseSelection.SelectedItem == "location")
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = leMars21StArguments;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string errOutput = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    p.Close();

    MessageBox.Show(errOutput);
}
```

Comment: So you are not going to include PsExec.exe with your program? What if they don't have it?

Comment: Yes I have the program PsExec added to my program, I want to use it without adding the whole directory path to use it. then I will make a installer program to my project so that file will always be within the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add it to your program, then you can just reference the location relative to your .exe where you place it.

For example, if you add a new folder called "Tools" to your project, and then add psexec.exe there, and set it to "Copy if newer" (or "Copy always"):

[image]

Then you can always get the path to it by grabbing the directory that your .exe is in and navigating to the "Tools" folder (note that you will need a reference to `System.Reflection` to use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly`):

```
var thisExeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var psExecPath = Path.Combine(thisExeDirectory, "Tools", "psexec.exe");
```

As an example:

```
var userInfo = new UserInfo {Password = "LetMeIn", Username = "rufusl"};
var thisExeDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var psExePath = Path.Combine(thisExeDirectory, "Tools", "psexec.exe");

var leMars21StArguments =
    "/C \"" + psExePath + @""" -i \\VML-2012-QBOOK2 -u mydomain\" + userInfo.Username +
    " -p " + userInfo.Password + @" -d C:\batch\myfile.bat";

Console.WriteLine(leMars21StArguments);
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hello Rufus, thanks for that, but now I am getting the following error

Comment: C:\users\aluna\Documents\Visual is not recognized as an internal or external command. Operable program or batch file. I added the string leMars21StArguments to my p.StartInfo = leMars21StArguments; and for some reason is giving me that error I added above. can you tell me what could be error. I am also doing a c# windows application form application not a c# console project.

Comment: That error is due to the fact that there are spaces in the file path, so the full path is not being read as a single argument. We need to enclose the full path and file name in quotes, so it's treated as one argument. I added a quote before the path using the `\ ` escape character (`"/C \""  + psExePath ...`). For the quote at the end of the string, I used a double-quote (`... psExePath + """ -i ..."`) since that string is prefixed with the `@` sign, which disables the escape character. I updated the output so you can see that the path is now quoted.

Comment: Hello Rufus, I made the changes as you explained and you are correct that fixed the issues, thanks bro, you are a coding genius. I learned a lot from this thanks again man.